# JavaFX terminate background task

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have external `Processor.process(...)` heavy method that can be running for a long time (tens of minutes) in normal case.

I want to show some loading screen with 'Cancel' button and run that `Processor` in background. I want to stop executing background task when 'Cancel' button clicked.

The problem is that I have a single call to `Processor.process(...)`.
If I had some task in a loop, I would do checks like `if( isCancelled() ){ break; }` or similar on each iteration.

Is there any way to **terminate|kill** that heavy background task? Let's assume that `Processor.process(...)` is very long 'atomic' operation (I just don't want to change all the logic deep behind it to accomplish this single task)

Here is how I start loading screen and background task:

```
private void handleProcess(ActionEvent event) {

    SomeService service = new SomeService();
    // ... configuring service

    Stage loadingStage = new Stage();
    // ... configuring 'loading' stage 

    service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Entity entity = (Entity) t.getSource().getValue();
            // ... do some stuff
            loadingStage.close();
        }
    });

    service.start();     // launch background process
    loadingStage.show(); // show 'loading' screen
}
```

**UPDATED** Here is Service for background job:

```
private static class SomeService extends Service<Entity> {
    private Thread threadToStopOnCancel;         // added
    // fields, getters, setters omitted 

    protected Task<Entity> createTask() {

        // _params initialization omitted
        return new Task<Entity>() {
            protected Entity call() throws IOException {
                 threadToStopOnCancel = Thread.currentThread();    // added
                 return Processor.process(_params);
            }
        };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void cancelled() {
        if (threadToStopOnCancel != null) { threadToStopOnCancel.stop(); }  // added
        super.cancelled();
    }
```

<del>For now, I call `service.cancel();` from loading screen. But it just sets the `service's` state to 'CANCELED', and the task is still working in background.</del>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service definition you can override the `cancelled()` method or pass an `EventHandler` to the `setOnCancelled()` method.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html#cancelled--).

Comment: Great, thanks. I've updated last snippet of code, it works now as expected, but it is a bit queerly for me. Can you suggest anything better?

Comment: I hadn't realized that the `cancelled()` method was deprecated. In any case, you can still get the same effect by creating a new `EventHandler` for the `setOnCancelled()` method as you've done with the `setOnSucceeded()` method

Comment: `cancelled()` isn't deprecated. I've added suppress for Thread's `stop()` method.

Comment: Ah, then what you're looking for is calling `interrupt()` on the thread. You will also need to catch the `InterruptedException` that gets thrown.

Comment: If I remember correctly,  `interrupt()` expects checking `isInterrupted()` in thread loop (similar to `isCancelled()` for `Service`), but I don't have this one. Seems thats the only way to achieve my goal. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, if there are no operations that throw `InterruptedException`, you would need to check `Thread.interrupted()` at some point in the thread execution and throw one yourself. Hopefully this won't be too much of a change to your heavy background task!